# Aggregate multiple rows of the same data.frame in R based on common values in given columns

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

I have a `data.frame` that looks like this:

```r
# set example data
df <- read.table(textConnection("item\tsize\tweight\tvalue
A\t2\t3\t4
A\t2\t3\t6
B\t1\t2\t3
C\t3\t2\t1
B\t1\t2\t4
B\t1\t2\t2"), header = TRUE)

# print example data
df
```

```
  item size weight value
1    A    2      3     4
2    A    2      3     6
3    B    1      2     3
4    C    3      2     1
5    B    1      2     4
6    B    1      2     2
```

As you can see the `size` and `weight` columns do not add any complexity since they are the same for each `item`. However, there can be multiple `value`s for the same `item`.

I want to collapse the data.frame to have one row per `item` using the mean `value`:

```
  item size weight value
1    A    2      3     5
3    B    1      2     3
4    C    3      2     1
```

I guess I have to use the `aggregate` function but I could not figure out how exactly I can get the above result.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
aggregate(value ~ item + size + weight, FUN = mean, data=df)

  item size weight value
1    B    1      2     3
2    C    3      2     1
3    A    2      3     5
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is the solution using the `ddply` from plyr package:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(df,.(item),colwise(mean))
  item size weight value
1    A    2      3     5
2    B    1      2     3
3    C    3      2     1
```

Comment: I just spent hours thinking through how to vectorize nested for loops trying to determine duplicate rows and average them, put them back into the data.frame, etc. This one-liner does the whole thing. Beautiful! About to invest in more education with the docs at https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/plyr/versions/1.8.4/topics/ddply. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

```
df$value <- ave(df$value,df$item,FUN=mean)
df[!duplicated(df$item),]

  item size weight value
1    A    2      3     5
3    B    1      2     3
4    C    3      2     1
```

Answer (score 3):

The `data.table` solution...

```
require(data.table)
DT <- data.table(df)

DT[ , lapply(.SD , mean ) , by = item ]
   item size weight value
1:    A    2      3     5
2:    B    1      2     3
3:    C    3      2     1
```

Answer (score 3):

Nowadays, this is what I would do:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(item, size, weight) %>%
  summarize(value = mean(value)) %>%
  ungroup
```

This yields the following result:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
   item  size weight value
  <chr> <int>  <int> <dbl>
1     A     2      3     5
2     B     1      2     3
3     C     3      2     1
```

I will leave the accepted answer as such as I specifically asked for `aggregate`, but I find the `dplyr` solution the most readable.