# Aggregate multiple rows in R based on common values in given columns by column indices

Tags: r, dplyr, grouping, aggregate

Here is a very similar question:

[Aggregate multiple rows of the same data.frame in R based on common values in given columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18228310/aggregate-multiple-rows-of-the-same-data-frame-in-r-based-on-common-values-in-gi)

In my situation, the selection of columns is changing in different simulated samples. I have the selected column indices in each simulation. How can I use the function `aggregate` on indices instead of variable names? Namely, in the answer of that [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18228310/aggregate-multiple-rows-of-the-same-data-frame-in-r-based-on-common-values-in-gi), how can I use a code like this:

```
c=c(1,2,3)
aggregate(value ~ df[,c], FUN = mean, data=df) # comparing to aggregate(value ~ item + size + weight, FUN = mean, data=df)
```

(Please note that the above line won't run in R.)

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without using the formula method, subset the column 'value' and the grouping columns in the `by` and specify the function

```
aggregate(df["value"], df[,c], FUN = mean)
#.  item size weight value
#1    B    1      2     3
#2    C    3      2     1
#3    A    2      3     5
```

---

With the formula method, subset the grouping columns along with the columns that we want to get the `mean` of and use `.` to specify all the columns in the subset dataset

```
aggregate(value ~ ., data= df[, c('value', names(df)[c])], mean)
#   item size weight value
#1    B    1      2     3
#2    C    3      2     1
#3    A    2      3     5
```

--

If we want to use `dplyr`, use `group_by_at` and specify the `c` variables in it

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by_at(c) %>% 
   # or extract column names, convert to symbol, and evaluate (!!!)
   #group_by(!!! rlang::syms(names(.)[c])) %>%
   summarise(value = mean(value))
# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Groups:   item, size [?]
#  item   size weight value
#  <fct> <int>  <int> <dbl>
#1 A         2      3     5
#2 B         1      2     3
#3 C         3      2     1
```

NOTE: The input dataset is taken from the link in the OP's post